# SoapUI HTTP request getting partial response

Tags: httprequest, response, soapui, partial

When I send a `http request` using `SoapUI`, I sometimes get back only a partial response. If I use some other client for making the request, I get the whole thing back, so it's a problem in SoapUI.

As it seems the problem is the length of the T&C of the signup form I'm getting back in the response. The T&C have *+15k characters*. The process of waiting on the response ends before the whole response gets through which causes my Test Step to fail.

Comment: Can you please add more details about your environment such os, version of soapui and its edition. Also, if possible, some will reproduce the problem consistently?

Comment: I'm using SoapUI 5.0.0 cause the 5.2.1 version has a bug at HTTP monitoring. But also for this testStep the 5.2.1 version was used with same results, meaning sometimes I get the whole response and mostly only part of it.

Comment: Are you invoking service which is on some remote host? Do you think the latency is the issue or is it something that socket time is happening?

Comment: It's a POST request to ${#Project#ServerEndpoint}/proxy.php.
Latency and/or socket timeout I would say that they are not the problem, since times of successful responses vary - sometimes greather and sometimes lower compared to the times of not successful responses.

Comment: are you observing this behaviour for the same request and even if you get the same response  without data or size changes? or response size and data varies when you experience this issue?

Comment: It's always for the same request or let's say for two requests where T&C contain over 15k characters, in environments where these are smaller the response is allwasy good.
Here are the times and sizes:
105ms (18695 bytes)
106ms (18695 bytes)
97ms (14371 bytes)
103ms (18695 bytes)
104ms (18695 bytes)
110ms (17291 bytes)
106ms (17291 bytes)
104ms (14371 bytes)

So response time realy doesn't seem to matter on how much of the response is obtained.
Also the response is just cutted of in the middle of T&C.
Server is also returning the whole response,the only thing is that it is not shown in SoapUI.

Comment: Looks something is missed and you did not mention is the response gets changes even for the same request? Why not update the question with all the data?

Comment: The response is always the same, only once in a while the whole response is displayed (all T&C with all signup fields), and mostly only a part of it is displayed (only part of T&C without any further data about the signup fields).
To reffer on the previous post, 18695bytes is the whole response.

Answer (score 1):

SoapUI has a [maximum response size](https://www.soapui.org/working-with-soapui/reference/preferences-and-settings.html). Increase it, or set it to zero (unlimited).

There is also "Size of Raw Response Message". Same link, same settings.

Comment: Max response size is by default set to unlimitet. Also this would not explain why a response is sometimes partial and sometimes whole.

Comment: @Lex90 How about: "Size of Raw Response Message"?

Comment: Size of raw response is currently set to 10.000, but was also changed to 250.000.
Wouldn't this cause the testStep always to return the same response and not once only part and the other time the whole one?